# L1 norm and completing the square

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Given $|u|^2_1 + |v|_1^2 - 2\langle u, v\rangle$, where $|a|_1$ is the one norm defined by $|a|_1 = \sum_i \text{abs}(a_i)$, can one "complete the square" somehow and express it as a single 1-norm quantity (at least an inequality, if not an equality)?

The analogy in case of the two norm is $|u|^2_2 + |v|_2^2 - 2\langle u, v\rangle = |u -v|^2_2$ but I cannot see how to come up with a simpler expression in the case of the 1 norm.

Comment: You are mixing a norm and an inner product that are not meant to go together... In fact, the only $p-$norm associated to an inner product is the euclidean norm ($p=2$).

Comment: "Somehow", in finite dimensions yes: $|u|_1^2+|v|_1^2-2\langle u,v\rangle\le|u|_2^2+|v|_2^2-2\langle u,v\rangle=|u-v|^2_2\le n|u-v|_1^2$.

Comment: @Chrystomath how do you get the first inequality? I thought $|u|_1^2 = (\sum \text{abs}(u_i))^2 \geq \sum u_i^2 = |u|^2_2$?

Comment: @PierreCarre I understand what you're saying but given that the p-norms are non increasing or using some other relationship, I was hoping to go along the lines posted by Chrystomath

Comment: @user1936752, I get your point and I am not saying that it is not possible. I'm just saying that unless you have a very specific motivation it does not seem coherent to mix "euclidean" inner product with 1-norms.

Comment: @user1936752 You're right, I swapped them in the morning rush.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility: $$|u|_1^2+|v|_1^2-2\langle u,v\rangle \le |u|_1^2+|v|_1^2+2|u|_2|v|_2\le |u|_1^2+|v|_1^2+2|u|_1|v|_1=(|u|_1+|v|_1)^2=|w|_1^2,$$ where $w$ is the vector/sequence $(|u_i|+|v_i|)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$.

Moreover, in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $$|u|_1^2+|v|_1^2-2\langle u,v\rangle\le n|u|_2^2+n|v|_2^2+2n|\langle u,v\rangle| \le n|u\pm v|_2^2\le n|u\pm v|_1^2$$
where $|\langle u,v\rangle|=\pm\langle u,v\rangle$.